# Jquery access to selectbox text not value how?

Tags: jquery, html-select

example:

```
<select>
<option value='1'>hello me<option>
<option value='2'>hello world</option>
</select>
```

how can I access a  TEXT not VALUE from select box

so I can display **HELLO ME** or **HELLO WORLD** instead of **1 & 2**.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`text`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) together with the [`:selected`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/selected) form selector:

```
$('select option:selected').text()
```

Loop over all options' texts and values:

```
$('#mySelect option').each(function () {
    console.log(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

Grab all option texts into an array:

```
var textArr = $('#mySelect option').map(function (i,n) {
    return $(n).text();
}).get();
console.log(textArr.join(','));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access the text of the selected option you might use:

```
$("#list option:selected").text();
```

Alternatively you could access the option directly this way:

```
$("#list option[value=2]").text();
```

`#list` is the id of the specific select. You should assign an id (e. g. `<select id="list">`) in order to avoid conflicts with other select tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $(option[value='1']).text();
```